# Projective scheme over a ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

I’m reading Qing Liu’s *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*. I’m confusing  my double definitions of projective morphism over a ring $A$.
In definition 2.3.42, projective scheme over $A$ is an $A$-scheme that is isomorphic to a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Proj} A[x_0,...,x_n]$.
In definition 3.1.11, $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec A}$ is projective if it factors in to a closed immersion $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Proj} A[x_0,...,x_n]$ followed by the canonical morphism $\operatorname{Proj} A[x_0,...,x_n] \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$.
So I think A scheme $X$ can be said projective in definition 3.1.11 sense.
So I think this two definitions should be coincide.

I can understand if $X$ is projective in the sense of definition 3.1.11, $X$ is projective in the sense of 2.3.42.
But I can’t understand the converse, when $X$ is projective in the sense of 2.3.42, why does $f:X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$ have a decomposition two morphisms.

Comment: Please put all of your math inside math mode and use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ and the like. I've made this upgrade for you this time - you can check out what I did via the [edit] button.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Sorry, I’m not used to using stack exchange. I should not do the same mistakes hereafter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a scheme $S$, an $S$-scheme is a scheme $X$ together with a morphism $X \to S$ (often referred to as the *structure map*), and a morphism of $S$-schemes is a morphism of schemes $X \to Y$ such that the structure map $X \to S$ factors as $X \to Y \to S$. So, phrased in this language, the second definition literally just says that $X$ can be realized as a closed $A$-subscheme of some projective space over $A$. The factorization of $X \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ as a composition $X \to \operatorname{Proj} A[x_0, \dots, x_n] \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is encoded in the fact that a projective scheme over $A$ is (by definition) an $A$-scheme, and the isomorphism to a closed subscheme of projective space is a morphism of $A$-schemes.

Comment: Here $S$ is the base scheme and the $S$-scheme  $X$ can be thought of as $moduli$ space. Am I right ?

Comment: Yeah, in your context, $S = \operatorname{Spec} A$, I just stated it in general since there's no need to restrict to affine schemes in that definition. There are lots of ways to think of a morphism of schemes $X \to S$; one useful interpretation is that it's a *family* of schemes, with members of the family corresponding to fibers of the morphism. I'm not sure "moduli space" is quite the right word for it, since that generally refers to a space parametrizing some objects *up to isomorphism*.

Comment: Yes, it is appropriate to use the term $\text{family of schemes}$ instead of $\text{moduli space}$. I agree

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can’t understand why the following morphism is A-scheme, “the isomorphism to a closed subscheme of projective space is a morphism of A-schemes” . In the first definition, dose that isomorphism mean A-scheme isomorphism?

Comment: @masui: Yes, it does mean isomorphic as an $A$-scheme, not just as an abstract scheme (without the structure map).

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand very well!!